# 2D Lighting directional shadows?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, render, light

So I'm making a 2D game and want "realistic" lighting effects. I'm using the 2D lighting that comes with the LWRP Package i saw in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkgGyO9VG54

Now it looks like this:
[image: How it looks right now]

But i want my objects to throw directional shadows, like this:

[image: How i want it to look]

I am a beginner when it comes to shaders and stuff like that.
Hope there is a not-too-complicated solution :)

Comment: you have to put a shadow renderer on the cube try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5l8vP90EvU

Comment: Thanks that’s just what I needed. Need to find a way to make it work for tilemaps tho

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shadow Caster 2D, it comes with URP package.
You can add it to your object and edit it like you do with the colliders.