# Universal Render Pipeline 2d shadows in tilemap

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, shadow, tile, light

I‘m making a game that is based on tilemaps and i want „realistic” lighting and shadows.

**Is it possible to make some of the tilemap tiles throw directional shadows like with the shadowcaster2d component?**
I know I can edit the shape of the shadowcaster but I want it to automatically take the shape of the wall tiles.

Like this: 
[image: shadows should look like this]

Edit:

So I found this Video That Shows exactly what I want. Unfortunately it’s not unity :D
https://youtu.be/QsCfx-jjS0U

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your previous question? ([2D Lighting directional shadows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531238/2d-lighting-directional-shadows))

Comment: The difference is that I‘m talking about TileMaps. 
I got it working with regular objects but not with the tilemap. 
I see that the question seems similar but it really isn’t